# Joomla theme where to modify certain parts?

Tags: php, joomla

I am pretty experienced with wordpress but having a hard time modifying some areas of Joomla templates,
the template is,

http://demo.joomla-monster.com/177-jm-web-development

I have already installed it and can access it administration area but I couldn't be able to find the area where I can modify the footer links , or slide show images under "our latest releases..." heading or the news in the left widget.

I have looked under Extensions -> Template Manager to modify the widget or footer but there is no such option.

Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: I'm curious, are you trying to edit links? If so, have you made sure they aren't located in the Joomla menu part? And slider images in the modules part?

Comment: No, these are not available under slide-show, neither there is a menu to modify the links from that footer (by footer, I mean the widget in the footer with blue background with sections like popular news, faq questions etc)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you should be Looking under Extensions -> Modules and try to find something there, the template itself rarely holds any data but the layout (And files required for such)

Answer (score 0):

Your template has a position, see what position is the element that you want to edit.
http://demo.joomla-monster.com/177-jm-web-development
Look for the module in this position and edit it (for the banner). Menu footer likely to be edited in the "MENU", module in this position only displays menu items.

basic joomla https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Administrators

Comment: how to look for the positions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the module position by adding `?tp=1` to the end of your URL. For example, if you are looking to edit a module and not sure what position it is just go to `http://www.yoursite.com/?tp=1` and it will outline the name of your module positions.

To edit the footer links directly, if you go to menus, there should be a menu called "Footer Links" or something like that. You can modify/create links there.